# iif vs Rectangle in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, rectangles, iif

I have 2 Rectangles and depend on count value one of them should be hidden:

Rectangle Name="Rectangle1"
Rectangle Name="Rectangle2"

```
=IIF(First(Fields!countValue.Value, "invoice") = "2"), Rectangle1, (Nothing))
```

Answer (score 1):

An iif() works like:

```
iif(<Test Condition>, <Value if True>, <Value if false/not true>)
```

A hide expression works on the basis of TRUE = hidden.
So you would use something like..

```
iif(First(Fields!countValue.Value, "invoice") = "2"), FALSE, TRUE)
```

Use this on the rectangle you want to be visible when the first value in the "invoice" dataset is 2.

More information on hiding items in SSRS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/hide-an-item-report-builder-and-ssrs